# To find the number of coats employee return to them

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose an employee is checking coats at a party with n guests. Unfortunately, the employee forgets to tag the coats and does not know which coat belong to which guest. When the party ends, all of the guests line up to retrieve their coats. When a guest is at the front of the line, the employee simply brings a coat uniformly at random from the remaining coats. If it is correct, the guest takes it and leaves, otherwise the employee returns it and retrieves another coat uniformly at random (with replacement: The employee is truly forgetful).

(a) If X is the random variable corresponding to the number of coats the employee returns to their correct owners on the first try, find the value of E[X].

(b) If Y is the random variable corresponding to the total number of coats that the employee brings to guests (right or wrong), find the value of E[Y ]. [Hint: A geometric random variable with parameter p takes the value k with the probability that the first success in a series of weighted coin tosses (Bernoulli trials) each with probability p occurs on toss (or trial) k. The expected value of a geometric random variable with parameter p is 1/p.]

(c) Calculate the variance and standard deviation of X and Y .

I am not getting exactly how to find he hands over in first try. Can anyone help please?

Comment: So you are asking for (a)?

Comment: It would be great if I get the answer for part a and b

Comment: Have you tried linearity of expectation for a)? That is: $X=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i=1$ iff the first try by guest $i$ is okay (and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: So how to find $X_1$ and all in that case?

Comment: By the first guest there are $n$ choices so that $\mathbb EX_1=P(X_1=1)=\frac1{n}$.

Comment: So you mean all the events are equally likely? Can you please provide a bit explanation as well in the answer section

Comment: If the employee picks out a hat out $n$ hats then the probability that it is the correct hat is $\frac1n$. That is what I am saying in my former comment. If he is ready with the first guest and starts with the second then $n-1$ hats are left so that similary $\mathbb EX_2=P(X_2=1)=\frac{1}{n-1}$. Et cetera. This enables you to find $\mathbb EX=\mathbb E\sum X_i=\sum\mathbb EX_i$.

Comment: Okay so it means we would get $1/n +1/n-1 +..1/n-(n-1)$? So, what about part 2?

Comment: 'number of coats the employee returns to their correct owners on the first try' - do you mean the number of coats they observe $before$ success?

Comment: Also,$E[X]$ becomes a Harmonic Progression, so how would we calculate the variance of a HP?

Comment: You can write $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ where $Y_i$ denotes the number of tries needed at guest $i$. The $Y_i$ are independent and have geometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For (b) note that for the last customer the probability of success is $1$, for the penultimate one it is $\frac{1}{2}$ etc, and for the first one it is $\frac{1}{n}$. By linearity of the expectation, $\mathbf{E}[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{E}[Y_i] = 1+2+ \ldots n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$